# create div where i click within the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a sample of creating a div next to the cursor position on click:
[view sample](http://jsfiddle.net/biboy/ctKa4/238/)

It creates a div where i click inside the container div but clicking too close to the borders creates a div beyond the container. Divs created should appear entirely inside the container even if the cursor is too close to the border. What do I have to change or add? :)

Problem --> [MyImage goes beyond the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACPTt.jpg)

Goal -->[Red dots indicate the clicks done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7Rx.jpg)

*Note: I don't need the red dots.I just placed it there to show that when I click on that spot, the result would be the imagediv*

HTML:

```
<div id="contain">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {


$("#contain").click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX + 'px';
    var y = e.pageY + 'px';
    var img = $('<img src="" alt="myimage" />');
    var div = $('<div>').css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "left": x,
      "top": y
    });
    div.append(img);
    $(document.body).append(div);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#contain{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Remember, not only you need the mouse position, you also need the div position, then you subtract them. Use [$("...").position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: @Ibu - got it bro. e.g. `x = e.pageX - $('.container').offset().left + 'px';` and `y = e.pageY - $('.container').offset().top + 'px';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to append your div into the container and not in the body. After that set the `position` of your container to `relative`.

There's only two case of overflow : the `right` and the `bottom` of the container.
So you just have to check if the `position` clicked is higher than the `position` + the `size` of your image.

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#contain").click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX + 'px';
    var y = e.pageY + 'px';
    var img = $('<img src="" alt="myimage" />');
    var imgwidth = 68; //Here your image width
    var imgheight = 28; // Here your image height
    if((e.pageX+imgwidth)> ($(this).position().left + $(this).width()))
      x=($(this).position().left + $(this).width())-imgwidth +"px";
    if((e.pageY+imgheight)> ($(this).position().top + $(this).height()))
      y=($(this).position().top + $(this).height())-imgheight+"px";
    var div = $('<div class="content">').css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "left": x,
      "top": y
    });
    div.append(img);
    $(this).append(div);
  });
});
```

```css
#contain{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contain">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you use absolute positions and the new div don't know about the width of your Box.

To solve this, you should get the width of your text wrapper. 
and the width of your box.

Store this values as max x and maybe you do the same with y .

```
   $(function() {
          $("#contain").click(function(e) {
            var x = e.pageX;
            var y = e.pageY;
            var xMax = 300;
            var yMax = 300;
            var img = $('<img src="" alt="myimage" />');
            var div = $('<div>').css({
              "position": "absolute",
              "left": x + 'px',
              "top": y + 'px'
            });


            div.append(img);
            $(document.body).append(div);

            var imgHeight = img.outerHeight();
            if ((y + imgHeight) > yMax) {
                div.css('top', yMax - imgHeight);
            }

            var imgWidth = img.outerWidth();
            if ((x + imgWidth) > xMax) {
                div.css('left', yMax - imgWidth);
            }
          });
        });
```

This example works for me. The text is always in the box. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: And take care about this, what Ibu told. You also need to add the offset of the box to my code.

Answer (score 1):

check out : https://jsfiddle.net/bupwhfby/

JS :

```
contain.onclick = function(e){

   var div = document.createElement('div');

   div.style.position = 'absolute';
   div.style.top      = e.clientY + 'px';
   div.style.left     = e.clientX + 'px';

   div.innerHTML = 'Hello World'

   this.appendChild(div);

}
```

CSS :

```
html,body,#contain{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="contain"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to work just because your container is 100% wide thus the created Element would adjust it's size as it appear near the edge because it's also the edge of the entire document. It didn't really adjust the spawn-coordinates. If you show the container's borders, you'll see that clicking the furthest bottom-right, the div goes beyond the container. https://jsfiddle.net/bupwhfby/2/ https://jsfiddle.net/bupwhfby/3/

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Alexis' answer is what I was looking for --> http://jsfiddle.net/ctKa4/244/